# Tengo una lista grande de variables y quería saber cuales son las primeras 10 variables mas grandes de ese grupo (java)

Tags: java

Resulta que por curiosidad se me ocurrió hacer un programa que simule una ruleta de casino y haga 1000 tiradas. Hice un switch que suma 1 al contador cada vez que sale una de las 37 opciones dentro de la ruleta. Muestra cada vez que salió negro, cada vez que salió rojo y cada vez que salió en cada una de las casillas. Si quisiera ver las primeras diez casillas que más salieron ¿Cómo lo haría?

```
public class ruleton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(i= 0;i<10000; i++) {
        n1 = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((36 - 0) + 1));
        
        switch(n1) {
        case 0:
            c0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            c1++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 2:
            c2++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 3:
            c3++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 4:
            c4++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 5:
            c5++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 6:
            c6++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 7:
            c7++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 8:
            c8++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 9:
            c9++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 10:
            c10++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 11:
            c11++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 12:
            c12++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 13:
            c13++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 14:
            c14++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 15:
            c15++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 16:
            c16++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 17:
            c17++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 18:
            c18++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 19:
            c19++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 20:
            c20++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 21:
            c21++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 22:
            c22++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 23:
            c23++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 24:
            c24++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 25:
            c25++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 26:
            c26++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 27:
            c27++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 28:
            c28++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 29:
            c29++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 30:
            c30++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 31:
            c31++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 32:
            c32++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 33:
            c33++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 34:
            c34++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        case 35:
            c35++;
            contadorNegro++;
            break;
        case 36:
            c36++;
            contadorRojo++;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("El color rojo salio: " + contadorRojo + " veces");
    System.out.println("El color rojo salio: " + contadorNegro + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 0 salio " + c0 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 1 salio " + c1 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 2 salio " + c2 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 3 salio " + c3 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 4 salio " + c4 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 5 salio " + c5 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 6 salio " + c6 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 7 salio " + c7 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 8 salio " + c8 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 9 salio " + c9 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 10 salio " + c10 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 11 salio " + c11 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 12 salio " + c12 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 13 salio " + c13 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 14 salio " + c14 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 15 salio " + c15 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 16 salio " + c16 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 17 salio " + c17 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 18 salio " + c18 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 19 salio " + c19 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 20 salio " + c20 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 21 salio " + c21 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 22 salio " + c22 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 23 salio " + c23 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 24 salio " + c24 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 25 salio " + c25 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 26 salio " + c26 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 27 salio " + c27 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 28 salio " + c28 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 29 salio " + c29 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 30 salio " + c30 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 31 salio " + c31 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 32 salio " + c32 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 33 salio " + c33 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 34 salio " + c34 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 35 salio " + c35 + " veces");
    System.out.println("El numero 36 salio " + c36 + " veces");

    
    }
}
```

PD: No puse las definiciones adentro del codigo porque no me dejaba publicarlo al ser la mayoría del texto código.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en tu caso.. tenes que comparar todas con todas... porque lo ideal, hubiera sido que aramas un diccionario, (hashmap) y luego, de alguna forma lo ordenaras para obtener las diez mayores...

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar un TreeMap.

TreeMap en Java es una implementación concreta de la interfaz java.util.SortedMap. Proporciona una colección ordenada de pares clave-valor, donde las claves se ordenan según su orden natural o un Comparador personalizado pasado al constructor.

```
    TreeMap<Integer,Integer>mapita=new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
//esto ordenara los valores por clave de manera descendente
        
        mapita.put(c0,0);
        mapita.put(c1,1);
        .
        .
        mapita.put(c36,36);
```

y para visualizar los 10 mayores podes usar un forEach limitado

```
 mapita.entrySet().stream()
            .limit(10)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println("Clave: "+e.getKey()+ " Valor: "+e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reescribamos tu código para evitar la "terrible repetición"...

```
public class ruleton {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int numeros[] = new int[ 37 ];
    String num[] = new String[ 37 ];
    for( int i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
       num[ i ] = "" + i;         
    }
    int negro = 0;
    int rojo = 0;
    boolean esPar;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
       int n1 = 0 + (int) ( Math.random() * ( ( 36 - 0 ) + 1 ) );
       if( n1 != 0 ) {
          esPar = n1 % 2 == 0;
          if( n1 < 11 || n1 > 18 && n1 < 29 ) {
             if( esPar ) {
                negro++;
             }
             else {
                rojo++;
             }
          }
          else {
             if( esPar ) {
                rojo++;
             }
             else {
                negro++;
             }
          }
       }
       numeros[ n1 ]++;
    }
    boolean desordenado = true;
    while( desordenado ) {
       desordenado = false;
       for( int i = 0; i < numeros.length - 1; i++ ) {
          if( numeros[ i ] < numeros[ i + 1 ] ) {
             int aux = numeros[ i ];
             numeros[ i ] = numeros[ i + 1 ];
             numeros[ i + 1 ] = aux;
             String aux2 = num[ i ];
             num[ i ] = num[ i + 1 ];
             num[ i + 1 ] = aux2;
             desordenado = true;
          }
       }
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
       System.out.print( "El " + num[ i ] + " salio " );
       System.out.println( numeros[ i ] + " veces" );         
    }
    System.out.println( "salio " + negro + " veces el negro y " + rojo + " el rojo" );
}
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo, creamos el array que contendrá la cantidad de veces que sale cada número, y uno de cadenas, que contendrá el nombre del mismo, seguidamente, en el "for", instanciamos el array de nombres.
Generamos la variables **negro** y **rojo**, y un booleano (**esPar**) para determinar si el número salido los es.
Luego, en el segundo "for", generamos el aleatorio (revisa como lo creas, **36 - 0** no parece tener sentido), luego en los "if", determinamos en base al rango en el que se encuentra y si es par o no, el color, y aumentamos la variable correspondiente.
Para finalizar, con el algoritmo de la burbuja (si no sabes como funciona, no dudes en preguntar), ordenamos en paralelo, el "array" que contiene la cantidad de repeticiones con el de los nombres, solo nos queda imprimir el resultado.

Ahora vamos a hacer las cosas bien, usemos la POO.
Primero creamos la clase **Numero**, con sus atributos, getters y setters:

```
public class Numero {

   public static int negro = 0;
   public static int rojo = 0;
   int repeticiones = 0;
   String color;
   int valor;

   public Numero( int val, String col ) {
      valor = val;
      color = col;
   }

   public void aumenta() {
      repeticiones++;
      if( color.equals( "rojo" ) ) {
         rojo++;
      }
      if( color.equals( "negro" ) ) {
         negro++;
      }
   }

   public int getValor() {
      return valor;
   }

   public int getRepeticiones() {
      return repeticiones;
   }

   public int getRojo() {
      return rojo;
   }

   public int getNegro() {
      return negro;
   }
}
```

Como podes ver, declaré las variables **negro* y **rojo** como estáticas, de esta forma, todos los objetos instanciados comparten el mismo valor en ellas.
El método "interesante", es **aumenta**, que aparte de aumentar la cantidad de repeticiones, dependiendo del color (o ausencia del mismo) del objeto, aumentará el valor de **negro** o de **rojo** o ninguno.

Ahora veamos la clase principal:

```
public class Pri {

   Numero nums[] = new Numero[ 37 ];

   public Pri() {
      boolean negro = false;
      nums[ 0 ] = new Numero( 0, "" );
      for( int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
         if( i == 11 || i == 19 || i == 29 ) {
            negro = !negro;
         }
         negro = !negro;
         String color = negro ? "negro" : "rojo";
         nums[ i ] = new Numero( i, color );
      }
   }

   public void girarRuleta() {
      for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
         int n1 = 0 + (int) ( Math.random() * ( ( 36 - 0 ) + 1 ) );
         nums[ n1 ].aumenta();
      }
      for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
         System.out.println( nums[ i ].getValor() + " " + nums[ i ].getRepeticiones() );
      }
      System.out.println( nums[ 0 ].getNegro() + " " + nums[ 0 ].getRojo() );
   }

   public void ordenar() {
      boolean desordenado = true;
      while( desordenado ) {
         desordenado = false;
         for( int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++ ) {
            if( nums[ i ].getRepeticiones() < nums[ i + 1 ].getRepeticiones() ) {
               Numero aux = nums[ i ];
               nums[ i ] = nums[ i + 1 ];
               nums[ i + 1 ] = aux;               
               desordenado = true;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void mostrar() {
   for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
       System.out.print( "El " + nums[ i ].getValor() + " salio " +
                          nums[ i ].getRepeticiones() + " veces" );         
    }
    System.out.println( "salio " + nums[ 0 ].getNegro() + " veces el negro y " + nums[ 0 ].getRojo() + " el rojo" );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Pri pri = new Pri();
      pri.girarRuleta();
      pri.ordenar();
      pri.mostrar();
   }    
}
```

En ella tenemos un array con los objetos tipo **Numero** como único atributo.

En el constructor, instanciamos los objetos, asignandoles el valor y el color, para este último, separamos la instanciación del "0" (va sin color) y para el resto, sabemos que casi siempre, los colores se van "turnando", este comportamiento lo logramos con **negro = ! negro** y la linea siguiente, para los casos en que esta alternancia se rompe, el "if" actua, revirtiendo la futura reversión (valga la redundancia).

Luego tenemos la "acción" en el método **girarRuleta()**, casi no se puede comentar de tan sencillo, se genera el aleatorio, se ubica en el array el objeto **Numero** (cuyo valor coincide con la posición), y se invoca al método **aumenta**, que hace todo el trabajo.

Solo nos queda ordenar el array, y presentarlo.

Comment: No puedo votar todavía pero ¡Guau! Que buena respuesta. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido!!!